# How to post json ajax request to web API

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm unable to get json data from server side. The script calls the server method but no json data returned.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SendMail").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:2457/SendMail/SendMail/",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: "{htmlTemplate:" + "ABC" + "}",
            //crossDomain: true,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Successfully called');
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // console.log(errorThrown);

            }
        });
    });
});

 Function SendMail(htmlTemplate As String) As String
      Dim fname As String = Request.Form("htmlTemplate1")
      Dim lname As String = Request.Form("lname")
      Dim cmdSendMail As New SendMailCommand()
      Return "A"
    End Function
```

Comment: You dont need `http://localhost:2457/ `only the service name will be enough

Comment: Provide the `webapi` method as well.

Comment: WebApi controllers default to routes starting with /api/{Controller}/{Action}

Comment: it not working without "http://localhost:2457/ "

Comment: May be your webapi is running in different port

Comment: It's simple ,  if you can provide your `webapi` method then it is easy for us to provide solution.

Comment: <HttpPost>
    Function SendMail(htmlTemplate As String) As String
      Dim fname As String = Request.Form("htmlTemplate1")
      Dim lname As String = Request.Form("lname")
      Dim cmdSendMail As New SendMailCommand()
      Return "A"
    End Function

Comment: you are passing an `object` and expecting to receive a `string` in webapi. This is the reason you are not seeing the value of `htmlTemplate`.   As it is just a string you can pass it as `querystring`

Comment: also the correct way to pass data is `data: JSON.stringify("{htmlTemplate:" + "ABC" + "}")`

Comment: Yes, i did it. (data: JSON.stringify("{htmlTemplate:" + "ABC" + "}")

Comment: Its `data:JSON.stringify({ htmlTemplate: 'ABC' }),` and add `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SendMail").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/SendMail/SendMail/', 
              dataType: 'text',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data:JSON.stringify({htmlTemplate: "ABC"}),
              //crossDomain: true,
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
               console.log(data);
                   alert('Successfully called');
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```